# Positioning comment from dataframe in python + plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am graphing a line graph that I'd like to add text comments to some data points. The text is long and causes overlaps on the screen so I'd like to position the text better.

Suggestions on how to do this best? It seems like I may need to use annotations but I do not want to need to absolutely position each one. Is there a way to do this?

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df[('Data1')], 
    y=df[('Data2')], 
    name='Name',
    text=df[('DataComment')],
    textposition='top right',
    mode = "lines+text",
    )
```

Comment: Your current situation is not clear from the information in the question. I think the annotations in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#positioning-text-annotations-absolutely) will help you. There are criteria for display and graphing as coordinate criteria, and you can set them freely.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks, my question is how to position them properly.

I have dataframe with x,y,z where x,y are the data points and some points have comments in z. I would like the text from z positioned close to x,y but not where text would place them.
How do I offset them as annotations and place them?

<code>
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df[('Data1')], 
    y=df[('Data2')], 
    name='Name',
    )

fig.add_annotation(text="Absolutely-positioned annotation",
                  xref="paper", yref="paper",
                  x=0.3, y=0.3, showarrow=False)
<code>

Comment: Perhaps a more clear way of asking this, is it possible to move the trace text to be x pixels higher?

Comment: There is a yshift and an xshift, so you can offset from the annotation coordinates. See [this](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/).

Comment: Can you clarify your question by adding some details? What does your current output look like at the moment, and what would you like to achieve? Also at the moment [your question isn't reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) e.g. no one can run your code block. what does your DataFrame look like? Assuming that every point isn't labeled, does the `df['DataComment']` column have NaN for x,y coordinates that don't need a label?

Answer (score 0):

Although a reproducible example would help, I have created a DataFrame with a `DataComment` column containing the lengthy comment `"this is a really long comment that has an overlap"` which exceeds the boundaries of the plot and gets cut off.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Data1':[20,40,60,80,100],
    'Data2':np.random.randint(100, size=5),
    'DataComment':["short comment"] + [float("nan")]*3 + ["this is a really long comment that has an overlap"]
})

fig = go.Figure()
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df[('Data1')], 
    y=df[('Data2')], 
    name='Name',
    text=df[('DataComment')],
    textposition='top right',
    mode = "lines+text"
)
fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

One thing you can do to fix this is make the text wrap at a specified length. Before you pass `df['DataComment']` to `go.Scatter`, you can modify the DataFrame with the following code, which will insert a `<br>` tag every 10 characters so that the text will wrap when Plotly renders it using html.

```
## insert html breaks <br> into the string text
df['DataComment'] = df['DataComment'].fillna("")
df['DataComment'] = df['DataComment'].str.wrap(10)
df['DataComment']= df['DataComment'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '<br>'))

fig = go.Figure()
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=df[('Data1')], 
    y=df[('Data2')], 
    name='Name',
    text=df[('DataComment')],
    textposition='top right',
    mode = "lines+text"
)
fig.add_trace(trace1)
fig.show()
```

[image]